# AttributeError on method __setitem__

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have the following code:

```
class VectorN(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        if isinstance(param, int):
            self.dim = param
            self.data = [0.0] * param

        elif isinstance(param, tuple):
            self.dim = 3
            self.data = param
        #else:
            #raise TypeError("You must pass an int or sequence!")

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Vector" + str(self.dim) + ": " + str(self.data) + ">"

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)


    def __setitem__(self, key, item): 
        self.data[key] = item
```

Now when i try to call the `__setitem__` method using the following code,

```
w = VectorN((1.2, "3", 5))
w.setitem(0, 9.9)
print(z) 
print(w) 
print(z[0])
print(len(v))
```

it gives me:

> AttributeError: 'VectorN' object has no attribute 'setitem'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) is a [magic method](https://duckduckgo.com/?q="A+Guide+to+Python%27s+Magic+Methods"). It's a special function that allows you to create [container objects](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

Because it's a magic method, you need not call it directly by its name- rather, built-in aspects of the Python language control its behavior. Note that it's still just a normal method; you *could* call it by name, but then the syntax would be `w.__setitem__(0, 9.9)`.

By defining `__setitem__` you can instead set a value like so: `w[0] = 9.9`.

---

`__setitem__`, from [A Guide to Python's Magic Methods](https://duckduckgo.com/?q="A+Guide+to+Python%27s+Magic+Methods"):

> Defines behavior for when an item is assigned to, using the notation self[nkey] = value.

Comment: By the way the OP was using the incorrect name `setitem`, while it should be `__setitem__`. The double underscores are part of the name.

Comment: Thanks had to change it to a string from a tuple but that was easy.